# Make Raspberry Pi 2 into a video capture card

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

Is it possible to transform my Raspberry Pi 2 model B into a capture card, I now know it will not be able to record 1080p in 60fps but it can be a fun project.

Can I do it using a mix of C#/C++ and Python or is it possible at all?

Xbox 360

Raspberry PI 2 Model B running Rasbpian.

Main PC running latest version of Windows 10 with VS 2015 For Desktop and OpenSSH installed with Cygwin.

Comment: You could probably find a USB capture solution that will work. Though as you point out performance may be poor. I would only try this with a Pi2. Verified working USB TV Tuners and DVB devices can be found on elinux http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_TV_Tuners_and_DVB_devices

Comment: thanks for the tip. but i dont want to buy any extra stuff to it right now, but i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Raspberry Pi has no consumer-grade video
 inputs , your project is - as defined - impossible.

If you allow at least *some* additional components , it might be possible (Composite and HDMI  USB framegrabbers , if expensive , do exist).

Note that still leaves the software question unanswered , that is , if those devices work on Raspbian Linux in a satisfactory manner (or at all).

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what quality you could obtain if it indeed worked and it seem like a rather round about route to go but it's possible to set up a stream feed using a Pi Cam which can be read by VLC.   A quick google suggests Wireshark will capture RTP packets (?) and this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581778/how-to-write-rtp-h264-stream-as-a-file)talks about building packets into a file?

No idea but like you say interesting project for the right mind.

Comment: Capture card !=  IP Camera .... Do you propose to record the screen with a camera ?

Answer (score -2):

give up. unless you are going to use a USB to do it you'll never do it.

#nice_try

BUT let me know if you find another way
just comment

Comment: -1 A better answer would include an explanation as to why this is infeasible. Preferably, it would also include decent sentence structure and a nicer tone than *give up*.

Comment: How is  this in any way an answer to the question? What you have written  is down right rude and the continuation of such  behaviour  will get you banned from the site.

Answer (score -2):

Just saw this old thread...

It *is* possible to do what you are asking.  Check out PiCapture.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Please take the [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.